# speech balloon vs speech bubble usage and meaning

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english

I am from the UK, and am not familiar with the term "speech balloon".
I have always used and heard "speech bubble" instead.

Are the 2 meanings the same?
Is there some kind of difference in British/American English usage?
(I don't really use speech bubbles so could be due to lack of knowledge.)

Comment: Both terms are in use and mean the same thing - the white area that speech is written into in comics with an arrow pointing to the speaker.

Comment: I seem to have seen them described as 'call outs'. Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @WS2- it depends on what they're used for. IF they are on a diagram and are *calling out* or making specific note of a feature then they're a *call out* if they are in a comic containing spoken dialog then they are not a *call out* but rather a "speech balloon" or "speech bubble".  I might make a distinction between bubble and balloon based on the type of connector between the person and the speech.  if the connector is a series of small (or progressively larger bubbles) then I'd call it a bubble.  If it's a thin line like the string of a balloon, then I'd call it a balloon.

Comment: I'm partial to *speech dirigible*, but only if the speaker is running.

Comment: @Jim the series of bubbles of increasing size is usually used for thoughts, not speech. I think they usually lead to a cloud rather than an oval or rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings are the same. You can also use dialogue balloons or [word balloons](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~MA04/wood/ykid/illustrated.htm). Just make sure you're not mixing up speech bubbles with thought bubbles.